# Updating component templates with Vue.js + Webpack

Tags: intellij-idea, webpack, vue.js

I just switched to Vue.js from Angular, and I found the Single File Components terribly inconvenient for me. So I decided to add Webpack to my stack and require the template files using vue-html-loader. Everything works just fine so far, except for one problem, which is quite annoying though: back in Angular, I could edit a template, then update resources in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and see the difference in the browser. I tried to implement this using Webpack's watch, but the problem is, when I'm done editing file, I have to wait for several seconds before I can update resources, so that Webpack can recompile the bundle. If I just edit the file and instantly update resources, the difference can't be seen in browser, as Webpack finishes compiling after the resources update. I've been looking towards IDEA's file watchers and webpack-dev-server, but none of these seems to work the way I'd like to:

1. Edit HTML-file.
2. Update resources in IDE.
3. Refresh page in browser and see difference.

What's the most convenient way to implement this? I don't mind giving up Webpack if it was a wrong decision to use it.

Comment: Check out `vue-cli`. It comes with hot module reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Webpack [Hot Module Replacement](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack): when it's enabled, Webpack is watching your files, rebuilding only the changed module(s) once they change, so the compilation is instant. BTW, Angular hot reloading is actually based on Webpack HMR.
Another option is trying [vue-cli](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/hot-reload.html)